# Replacing values inplace in a pandas dataframe work not working with .replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with various gridstations and their connections with other grid stations and I need to map out transmission lines from this data. It looks something like this (there are about a 100 or so lines in the original dataframe):

```
>df

    Name    Latitude    Longitude   Link 1  Link 2  Link 3  Link 4  Link 5  
0   A       34.466667   72.200000   B       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
1   B       33.766667   72.366667   A       C       D       NaN     NaN
2   C       33.761500   72.434000   B       E       G       NaN     NaN
```

To make things easier I created a new dataframe indexed with names like this:

```
>datax

        Latitude    Longitude   Link 1  Link 2  Link 3  Link 4  Link 5
Name                                                    
A       34.466667   72.200000   B       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
B       33.766667   72.366667   A       C       D       NaN     NaN
C       33.761500   72.434000   B       E       G       NaN     NaN
```

I'm mapping out the lines using the 'Links' of each grid station, which show me the other grid stations it is connected to. Since each grid station shows its connection with others, to properly map the lines, I need to eliminate the duplicates, for example if I map out the first line between A and B by iterating over the first column of the dataframe, I need to eliminate this link (i.e. remove 'A' in the Link 1 column in second row) in the second row so the line doesn't get duplicated when I iterate over the second row. To accomplish this, I tried using replace,

```
datax.loc[datax.iloc[0]['Link 1']].replace(datax.index[0],np.nan)
```

This snippet does replace the link and puts in nan but doesn't do it in place in the original dataframe, so I tried the built in argument inplace,

```
datax.loc[datax.iloc[0]['Link 1']].replace(datax.index[0],np.nan, inplace=True)
```

But that doesn't seem to do it either. I'm somewhat of a novice coder, so I'm sorry but does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and how I can rectify this mistake, and if there is another easier method to this problem that I'm not getting.

Edit:

When I run the code snippet above, I want 'Link 1' in the second column of dataframe to become NaN.

```
>datax

        Latitude    Longitude   Link 1  Link 2  Link 3  Link 4  Link 5
Name                                                    
A       34.466667   72.200000   B       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
B       33.766667   72.366667   Nan     C       D       NaN     NaN
C       33.761500   72.434000   NaN     E       G       NaN     NaN
```

The problem is that the code does do this but does not save it to the dataframe in place. Since I have to do this process over hundreds of times for my original dataframe, I need to save the values in place to the dataframe instead of creating new ones every time which would be inefficient as hell.

Comment: How do I make the dataframe pasteable? Can you guide me a bit here? I think pd.read_clipboard() can do the job quite easily

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad, wrong page comment. Could you provide an output example that you want?

Comment: I've edited the original question and added a sample of the output I need. Hope it helps you in helping me figure this out.

Comment: @HamzaWaheed Is this what you're looking at? `datax.at['A', 'Link 1'] = np.NaN`

Comment: @davidbilla, for .at I need to have exact indices for the data, while replace can find the value itself in the column which is much more ideal since the data can be at any 'Link' instead of just Link 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.

**Step 1 -** First step is to sort the values of 'Name' and 'Link 1' along the column axis.

```
datax[['Name', 'Link 1']].apply(sorted, axis=1)
```

This gives you a list like this

```
0    [A, B]
1    [A, B]
2    [B, C]
```

**Step 2 -** Then you need to convert these to strings (beacuse lists are not accepted when you use `df.duplicated()`) using `.apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))`

**Step 3 -** Next, find the duplicates using `df.duplicated()` and store it in a new column 'temp'.

```
datax['temp'] = datax[['Name', 'Link 1']].apply(sorted, axis=1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).duplicated(keep='first')
```

At this stage your df `datax` will be

```
  Name   Latitude  Longitude Link 1 Link 2 Link 3  Link 4  Link 5   temp
0    A  34.466667  72.200000      B    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  False
1    B  33.766667  72.366667    NaN      C      D     NaN     NaN   True
2    C  33.761500  72.434000      B      E      G     NaN     NaN  False
```

**Step 4 -** Now, you can use `np.where()` and check if `datax['temp']` is True and assign `datax['Link 1']` accordingly

```
datax['Link 1'] = np.where(datax['temp']==True, np.NaN, datax['Link 1'])
```

**Step 5 -** You can drop the column `temp` after this using `datax.drop('temp', axis=1)`

**Output:**

```
  Name   Latitude  Longitude Link 1 Link 2 Link 3  Link 4  Link 5
0    A  34.466667  72.200000      B    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
1    B  33.766667  72.366667    NaN      C      D     NaN     NaN
2    C  33.761500  72.434000      B      E      G     NaN     NaN
```

**Combining all these steps -**

```
datax['temp'] = datax[['Name', 'Link 1']].apply(sorted, axis=1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).duplicated(keep='first')
datax['Link 1'] = np.where(datax['temp']==True, np.NaN, datax['Link 1'])
datax.drop('temp', axis=1)
```

**Final solution -** 
We can extend this solution to compare each of 'Link 1', 'Link 2', 'Link 3' etc with 'Name' and set the 'Link 1', 'Link 2', 'Link 3' cols respectively.

```
for column in datax[['Link 1','Link 2','Link 3','Link 4','Link 5']]:
    datax['temp'] = datax[['Name', column]]\
        .fillna('').apply(sorted, axis=1)\
        .apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))\
        .duplicated(keep='first')
    datax[column] = np.where(datax['temp']==True, np.NaN, datax[column])
    datax.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(datax)
```

**Output:**

```
  Name   Latitude  Longitude Link 1 Link 2 Link 3  Link 4  Link 5
0    A  34.466667  72.200000      B    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
1    B  33.766667  72.366667    NaN      C      D     NaN     NaN
2    C  33.761500  72.434000      B      E      G     NaN     NaN
```

Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: Thank you dude, your solution was perfect, I just made a new dataframe with duplicate transmission lines and then used your code to weed out the duplicates, worked like a charm. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Glad I was able to help